# Add a Thumbnail to Group Product Image in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

Currently woo commerce only offers the product name and quantity box. Some of my products are a different color or style. I would like the customer to be able to see a thumbnail image next to the product name that is a grouped product. Also if possible if they hover over it to see it larger.

```
Grouped.php file:

<?php
/**
 * Grouped product add to cart
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.1.7
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product, $post;

$parent_product_post = $post;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <table cellspacing="0" class="group_table">
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ( $grouped_products as $product_id ) :
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            $post    = $product->post;
            setup_postdata( $post );
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php if ( $product->is_sold_individually() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ) : ?>
                        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php
                        $quantites_required = true;
                        woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'input_name' => 'quantity[' . $product_id . ']', 'input_value' => '0' ) );
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>

                <td class="label">
                    <label for="product-<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo $product->is_visible() ? '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' : get_the_title(); ?>
                    </label>
                </td>

                <?php do_action ( 'woocommerce_grouped_product_list_before_price', $product ); ?>

                <td class="price">
                    <?php
                    echo $product->get_price_html();

                    if ( ( $availability = $product->get_availability() ) && $availability['availability'] )
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>', $availability['availability'] );
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        endforeach;

        // Reset to parent grouped product
            $post    = $parent_product_post;
            $product = wc_get_product( $parent_product_post->ID );
            setup_postdata( $parent_product_post );
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />

    <?php if ( $quantites_required ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-flat"><?php echo apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_text' , $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

Found this but doesn't seem to work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_product_list_before_price', 'woocommerce_grouped_product_thumbnail' );

function woocommerce_grouped_product_thumbnail( $product ) {
$image_size = array( 20, 20 );  // array( width, height ) image size in pixel 
$attachment_id = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_thumbnail_id', true );
?>
<td class="label">
    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $image_size ); ?>
</td>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it!
I use this code in another way:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Grouped product add to cart
 *
 * @author   WooThemes
 * @package  WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.1.7
 */


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product, $post, $image_size;
$image_size = array( 50, 50 );// array( width, height ) image size in pixel

$parent_product_post = $post;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <table cellspacing="0" class="group_table">
  <tbody>
   <?php
    foreach ( $grouped_products as $product_id ) :
     $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

     if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) && ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
      continue;
     }

     $post    = $product->post;
     setup_postdata( $post );
     ?>
     <tr>
      <?php $attachment_id = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_thumbnail_id', true ); ?>
      <td class="gpThumbs">
       <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $image_size ); ?> 
      </td>
      

      <td class="label">
       <label for="product-<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
        <?php echo $product->is_visible() ? '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' : get_the_title(); ?>
       </label>
      </td>

      <?php do_action ( 'woocommerce_grouped_product_list_before_price', $product ); ?>
      
      <td class="price">
       <?php
        echo $product->get_price_html();

        if ( $availability = $product->get_availability() ) {
         $availability_html = empty( $availability['availability'] ) ? '' : '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>';
         echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', $availability_html, $availability['availability'], $product );
        }
       ?>
      </td>
      <td>
       <?php if ( $product->is_sold_individually() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ) : ?>
        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>
       <?php else : ?>
        <?php
         $quantites_required = true;
         woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'input_name' => 'quantity[' . $product_id . ']', 'input_value' => '0', 'min_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 0, $product ), 'max_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity(), $product ) ) );
        ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
      </td>
      
     </tr>
     <?php
    endforeach;

    // Reset to parent grouped product
    $post    = $parent_product_post;
    $product = wc_get_product( $parent_product_post->ID );
    setup_postdata( $parent_product_post );
   ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />

 <?php if ( $quantites_required ) : ?>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

  <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

it workes fine :)